# Installing GLFW 3.0 not working Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lnk2019, glfw

I'm trying to create a GLFW project, but I'm getting LNK2019 errors with the basic setup.

1. I've downloaded the latest binary (glfw-3.0.bin.WIN32.zip) to a folder.
2. I've created a new, empty console project.
3. Within VC++ Directories, I've added the following line to include directories:

   **C:\C++Libraries\glfw-3.0.bin.WIN32\include**
4. I've added the following line to the Library Directories:

   **C:\C++Libraries\glfw-3.0.bin.WIN32\lib-msvc110**
5. I've linked the following libraries:

**opengl32.lib**, **glfw3.lib**,  **glfw3dll.lib**

1. From the [latest tutorial](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html), I paste into my project (no visible syntax errors) to test, but I get **four** LNK2019 errors after trying to run it.

   Here are the errors:

   ```
   Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__joyGetPosEx@8
   referenced in function __glfwPlatformGetJoystickAxes    
   c:\Users\Spicy Weenie\documents\visual studio 2012\
   Projects\Beta\Beta\glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)

   Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__joyGetDevCapsW@12  
   referenced in function __glfwPlatformGetJoystickAxes    
   c:\Users\Spicy Weenie\documents\visual studio  
   2012\Projects\Beta\Beta\glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)

   Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__joyGetPos@8
   referenced in function __glfwPlatformJoystickPresent    
   c:\Users\Spicy Weenie\documents\visual studio
   2012\Projects\Beta\Beta\glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)

   Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__timeGetTime@0
   referenced in function __glfwInitTimer  c:\Users\Spicy Weenie\documents\visual 
   studio 2012\Projects\Beta\Beta\glfw3.lib(win32_time.obj)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link in at least winmm.lib for timeGetTime. The joystick code is probably in there to.